# selecting uploaded images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of uploaded images in a div. For example this: http://jsfiddle.net/CymEv/
I want to select multiple images from the list (by clicking on it, and deselect by clicking again (eg. toggle), and I want to get the names of selected images. How can I do this by using php and jquery? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to add some clicking events.

For example:

```
$('img').click(function()
{
    //do something nice like getting the names in the list
    //or add a class to it
});
```

php is not the way to go here, because you need to do things in the browser, not on the server.
Check the website from jQuery and see some nice functions in the API to do something cool with this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery UI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/). Demo on its way.

And here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/CymEv/1/

Comment: Thanks. Can you possibly tell how can i select multiple images, and also, how can i get the images name on submit?

Comment: @John - I could do that, by reading through the UI Selectable documentation. But since I have never used it, I would suggest that you read it and figure out how to use it - since after all, you are the one who needs it. (I'm not trying to sound like an asshat - I honestly think this will help you). Once you have read through it and tried stuff out, and it does not work, I will be glad to help.